# What type of phrase is the second phrase in the following sentence? Is it perfectly grammatical?

Tags: grammar, phrases

"She looked through the text, editing all the errors."

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/intermediate-grammar/participle-clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *"editing all the errors"* that you are asking about, is a participle phrase. In other words, it is "a group of present-participle (verb + ing)...and other linked words. [It] is punctuated with a comma or commas." [See more here, the source](http://www.studyandexam.com/types-of-phrase.html).

Answer (score 1):

A participle phrase, and it is.